# I have saved a hadoop3.pem file in the downloaded section . but the chmod command cannot acces this

Tags: permissions

```
sudo chmod 600 /path/to/hadoop3.pem
```

This command shows:

```
chmod: cannot access '/path/to/hadoop3.pem': No such file or directory
```

There is a `hadoop3.pem` file downloaded in the download section

Comment: What's the output of `file /path/to/hadoop3.pem`?

Answer (score 1):

`/path/to/hadoop3.pem` isn't some magical file path that finds the `hadoop3.pem` file. You actually need to specify the "path to hadoop3.pem." If it's in your Downloads folder, it'll be

```
~/Downloads/hadoop3.pem
```